# What causes a 403 error when the URL payload contains '_REQUEST'

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

I was experiencing intermittent 403 errors while testing an API and it turned out that it would happen if the URL happened to have the text '_REQUEST' anywhere in it. I've identified the problem, but cannot find the security mechanism which (stupidly in my opinion) is triggering this behaviour.

I've simplified the initially complex scenario down to this:

```
mydomain.com/?foo=_REQUEST   => causes 403

mydomain.com/?foo=_REQUES    = is fine
```

It's a test host, on Windows 2008 AWS, XAMP 3.2.1, PHP Version => 5.5.3 everything is pretty much out of the box configured for dev.

I read about mod_security, but that's not found in my httpd.conf.

Is this a known PHP security mechanism, or something XAMP has added, or an Apache feature?

Answer (score -2):

i think request is reserve word so it is giving error.
you cant use request, post, files, get in url

Comment: Not true. There should be no problem passing any of those strings as a GET values, unless the server especially forbid so.

Comment: False information

Comment: @E-telier by default these words are reserved in most os, try urself